# REST Upload attachments - Json Deserialization failed on token 'null'

Tags: rest, attachment, base64, simple-salesforce

I'm using `simple-salesforce` to migrate attachments from one org to another. I'm encoding with base64 but am getting this error:

```
SalesforceMalformedRequest: Malformed request 
https://my_org.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Attachment/. 
Response content: [{
   'message': "Json Deserialization failed on token 'null' and has left off in the middle of parsing a row. Will go to end of row to begin parsing the next row", 
   'errorCode': 'INVALID_FIELD'}]
```

I've tried different attachment types but am not having any luck. Below is the code I'm using to test.

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
from base64 import b64encode
import json

userName = 'my_username@test.com'
password = 'mypw'
securityToken = 'mytoken'
svc = Salesforce(username=userName, password=password, security_token=securityToken)
ENCODING = 'utf-8'
name = 'test.txt'
parent_id = '5001I000006rNenQAE'


with open(name, 'rb') as open_file:
    byte_content = open_file.read()
    base64_bytes = b64encode(byte_content)
    base64_string = base64_bytes.decode(ENCODING)
    json_data = json.dumps({
                    'ParentId' : parent_id,
                    'Name' : name,
                    'Body' : base64_string
                    })

    result = svc.Attachment.create(json_data)
    print(result)
```

Am I missing something obvious? The error `Json Deserialization failed` is only coming up in questions about apex not uploading via REST API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`simple_salesforce` methods don't take JSON strings as parameters, generally - they take Python dicts directly.

```
svc.Attachment.create({ 'ParentId': parent_id, 'Name': name, 'Body': base64_string })
```

should work just fine; I've tested it out in my developer org. Presumably the extra layer of serialization is causing the `null` issue somewhere between your Python and Salesforce (since Python itself doesn't use the keyword `null`).